# Searching and replacing specific string using Python

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to write a python script that will search and replace specific string in text file

As an example foo.txt is like that:

```
[section1]
option1=xyz
option2=abc

[section2]
option1=aaa
option2=bbb
```

My objective is to replace only option1 and option2 values under section2 without changing anything in section1 as the following be:

```
[section1]
option1=xyz
option2=abc

[section2]
option1=xxx
option2=zzz
```

I have tried pysed and many other methods with no dice. Any help from Python Guru ?

Comment: you don't need a python guru for that question. you just need to read doc about how to read files. there are needed methods for your question. just search for sectionX and section(X+1) and read and delete option1 and option2, after that replace that options.
i finded a tutorial easily, just learn how to use google and don't be afraid of reading. here is the link: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: I would use regex, try looking at the python docs for `re`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) instead of searching and replacing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
import ConfigParser                                                             
import os                                                                       

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open('foo.txt'))
config.set("section2", "option1", "xxx1")
config.set("section2", "option2", "yyy1")
# It's always better to write to a temporary file
# and then atomically replace the original:
config.write(open('foo.txt.new', "w"))
os.rename('foo.txt.new', 'foo.txt')
```

Comment: Awesome !  Worked as expected. Thanks